# VBScript not running through other program

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get another programm to execute a VBScript (not mine). The script extends my screen to a second screen and then executes KODI, so it will run fullscreen on that screen. After closing KODI, it reverts back to one screen. The VBScript works fine if I doubleclick it in Windows 10. Using Push2run in various ways, however, result in a Windows Script Host error

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Code: 80070002
>   Line 14
>   Char 1
>   Source (null)

I've tried Push2Run calling upon a selfmade bat file instead of the vbs directly. Tried giving rights to 'everyone' on the vbs file. Tried admin privileges on Push2Run. All giving the same error.

The script:

```vb
Dim WshShell
Dim scv
Set svc = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const DELAY = 1

'switch to TV only
'execCMD = """C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe""/external"
'Wshshell.Run execCMD, 2, False

'Extend display
execCMD = """C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe""/extend"
Wshshell.Run execCMD, 2, False

'Launch Xbmc
WScript.Sleep 10000
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\"
execCMD = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"""
Wshshell.Run execCMD, 3, True

'switch to LCD only
execCMD = """C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe""/internal"
Wshshell.Run execCMD, 2, False
```

Comment: Spaces separate parameters, so put them in.

Comment: perhaps this post will help 
https://www.push2run.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=723

Comment: @Noodles Do you mean between 'execCMD,2,false' ?

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the link!  Maybe a good workaround.

Comment: If the VBScript works when run directly, but not when run from some other launcher, the problem is not with the VBScript code. How are you invoking the VBScript in Push2run or your batch script?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers In Push2run you can select any executables (exe,bat) or script to open, and add the start directory, parameters, keys to send, but also open it with admin priveleges and in a certain window state. In my case I've tried several ways; let it open the vbs directly, a link to the vbs and open a self created .bat file that then opens the vbs. All with the same error, while clicking it directly works. The bat file tries were 'cd C:\GoogleHome\
WSCript xbmc_switch.vbs' and a same version with a Cscript.

Comment: Show, don't tell. [Edit] your question and show both your exact batch code as well as what settings you tried in Push2run.